# Type definition with a trait: Differences of specifying an explicit lifetime bound?

Tags: types, rust, traits

I'm having issues understanding the lifetime bound requirements when I use a trait in a type definition. For instance:

```
trait Kind { /* ... */ }
type CollectionOfKind<'a> = Vec<&'a Kind>;
// => error: explicit lifetime bound required
```

The requirement for lifetime bounds has already been discussed for the case of a trait within a struct ([Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25959791/1804173), [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26213294/1804173)). At first, I had problems to apply the approach of "adding the lifetime" here at all, since this does not work:

```
type CollectionOfKind<'a> = Vec<&'a Kind + 'a>;
type CollectionOfKind<'a> = Vec<&'a Kind + 'static>;
```

However, this was only a syntax issue, due to the [precedence of plus](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0438-precedence-of-plus.md) as pointed out by @Shepmaster.

Overall, I now have found three ways to specify the lifetime bounds:

```
// Version 1: Adding 'static to the trait itself
trait Kind : 'static { /* ... */ }
type CollectionOfKind<'a> = Vec<&'a Kind>;
```

```
// Version 2: Adding 'static to the type definition
trait Kind { /* ... */ }
type CollectionOfKind<'a> = Vec<&'a (Kind + 'static)>;
```

```
// Version 3: Adding the lifetime of the reference to the trait object (?)
trait Kind { /* ... */ }
type CollectionOfKind<'a> = Vec<&'a (Kind + 'a)>;
```

What I don't understand: What is the exact difference between these three cases?

**My problems:**

In order to see the differences, I was trying to understand certain points mentioned in the other answers. For instance in the above linked Answer 2, I have found the following hint which I do not fully understand:

> In this case, the `'static` requires that the underlying object must be a real struct, or a `&'static` reference, but other references won't be allowed.

What does it mean that the underlying object must be a "real" struct? How is it possible for a struct to implement the trait without being "real"?

Similarly for the quote that @Shepmaster has cited:

> You have to specify the lifetime two times: once for the lifetime of the reference, and once for the trait object itself, because traits can be implemented for references, and if the underlying object is a reference, you must specify its lifetime as well.

To be honest, I don't see why it must be specified twice. I though a trait object is defined by being a reference to an object which implements a certain trait. So it is by definition (?) a reference, and thus, has a lifetime anyways?

Comment: In what way does `&'a Kind + 'a` not work?

Comment: @dbaupp: _error: expected a path on the left-hand side of `+`, not `&'a Kind` [E0178]_. However I just saw that `&'a (Kind + 'a)` does work! (I could have sworn that it failed when I tried it before...). But I still don't understand the effects of this lifetime bounds in general.

Comment: I found the comment above the one you cited to be useful as well: `You have to specify the lifetime two times : once for the lifetime of the reference, and once for the trait object itself, because traits can be implemented for references, and if the underlying object is a reference, you must specify its lifetime as well.`

Comment: @bluenote10 I've updated my answer with your revised question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Answer for new question

You really have [two orthogonal cases](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f5b15ca2c50b911504ce187c0507354b) . I'll tackle the easier one first, the difference of #2 and #3. Comments are inline with what I hope is a representative example:

```rust
trait Kind { 
    fn trait_fn(&self) -> u8 { 0 }
}

type CollectionOfKind1<'a> = Vec<&'a (dyn Kind + 'static)>;
type CollectionOfKind2<'a> = Vec<&'a (dyn Kind + 'a)>;

struct Alpha;
impl Kind for Alpha {}

struct Beta<'b> {
    name: &'b str,
}
impl<'a> Kind for Beta<'a> {}

fn main() {
    let name = "world".to_string();

    // Doesn't need/have it's own lifetime.
    let a = Alpha;
    // Has a reference to something with the 'static lifetime.
    let b1 = Beta { name: "hello" };
    // Has a reference to something with the lifetime of `name`,
    // which is less than 'static.
    let b2 = Beta { name: &name[..] };  

    // Our vector is composed of references to
    // things that *might* have a reference themselves!
    let mut c1: CollectionOfKind1 = Vec::new();
    c1.push(&a);
    c1.push(&b1);
    // c1.push(&b2); // error: `name` does not live long enough
    
    let mut c2: CollectionOfKind2 = Vec::new();
    c2.push(&a);
    c2.push(&b1);
    c2.push(&b2); // Hooray
}
```

Of note here is that the lifetimes *don't have to be the same*! You could have written:

```rust
type CollectionOfKind2<'a, 'b> = Vec<&'a (dyn Kind + 'b)>;
```

The second thing is the meaning of `trait Foo : 'static`. I'm less sure here, but I wrote this small example:

```rust
trait Foo : 'static {}

fn x(a: &Foo) {}

fn main() {
    x(&3u8);
}
```

This errors during compilation with

> the trait `Foo` must be implemented for the cast to the object type `Foo + 'static`

Based on that, I think that `Foo : 'static` is just another way of writing `Foo + 'static`. The main difference I can think of is that it restricts the trait from *ever* being implemented on a struct with non-`'static` lifetimes:

```rust
struct B<'a> {
    b: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Foo for B<'a> {}
```

Has the error

> declared lifetime bound not satisfied [...] but lifetime parameter must outlive the static lifetime

#### Original answer

I see you've found this out already, but you may want to update your version of Rust. If I compile your code on the Playpen, I get a suggestion on how to fix it:

```rust
error: expected a path on the left-hand side of `+`, not `&'a Kind` [E0178]
type CollectionOfKind<'a> = Vec<&'a Kind + 'a>;
                                ^~~~~~~~
note: perhaps you meant `&'a (Kind + 'a)`? (per RFC 438)
type CollectionOfKind<'a> = Vec<&'a Kind + 'a>;
                                ^~~~~~~~
```

That references [RFC 438, *Precedence of Plus*](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0438-precedence-of-plus.md).

Comment: Wow, perfect summary, now this makes sense. Thanks a lot!