# Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter while implementing Deref trait

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement `Deref` for an enum:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::ops::Deref;

pub trait tObject {
    fn name(&self) -> String;
    fn span(&self) -> u32;
}

pub struct t1 {
    pub name: String,
    pub bd: Option<String>,
    pub span: u32,
    pub label: Option<String>
}

pub struct t2 {
    pub name: String,
    pub vrf: Option<String>,
    pub span: u32,
    pub label: Option<String>,
    pub svi: u32
}

pub struct t3 {
    pub name: String,
    pub span: u32,
    pub label: Option<String>
}

impl tObject for t1 {
    fn name(&self) -> String {self.name.clone()}
    fn span(&self) -> u32 {self.span.clone()}
}

impl tObject for t2 {
    fn name(&self) -> String {self.name.clone()}
    fn span(&self) -> u32 {self.span.clone()}
}

impl tObject for t3 {
    fn name(&self) -> String {self.name.clone()}
    fn span(&self) -> u32 {self.span.clone()}
}

pub enum TType {
    t1(Rc<t1>),
    t2(Rc<t2>),
    t3(Rc<t3>)
}

impl Deref for TType {
    type Target = tObject;
    fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a tObject {
        match *self {
            TType::t1(ref x) => x as &t1,
            TType::t2(ref x) => x as &t2,
            TType::t3(ref x) => x as &t3
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut t1s: Vec<Rc<t1>> = Vec::new();
    let mut t2s: Vec<Rc<t2>> = Vec::new();
    let mut t3s: Vec<Rc<t3>> = Vec::new();

    let t_iter: Box<Iterator<Item=TType>> = Box::new(t1s.iter().map(|x| TType::t1(x.clone())).chain(
                                                t2s.iter().map(|x| TType::t2(x.clone())).chain(
                                                t3s.iter().map(|x| TType::t3(x.clone())))));
}
```

The compiler reports this error:

```
rustc 1.15.1 (021bd294c 2017-02-08)
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter 'a in generic type due to conflicting     requirements
  --> <anon>:53:5
   |
53 |       fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a tObject {
   |  _____^ starting here...
54 | |         match *self {
55 | |             TType::t1(ref x) => x as &t1,
56 | |             TType::t2(ref x) => x as &t2,
57 | |             TType::t3(ref x) => x as &t3
58 | |         }
59 | |     }
   | |_____^ ...ending here
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 53:42...
  --> <anon>:53:43
   |
53 |       fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a tObject {
   |  ___________________________________________^ starting here...
54 | |         match *self {
55 | |             TType::t1(ref x) => x as &t1,
56 | |             TType::t2(ref x) => x as &t2,
57 | |             TType::t3(ref x) => x as &t3
58 | |         }
59 | |     }
   | |_____^ ...ending here
note: ...so that method type is compatible with trait (expected fn(&TType) -> &tObject + 'static, found     fn(&TType) -> &tObject)
  --> <anon>:53:5
   |
53 |       fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a tObject {
   |  _____^ starting here...
54 | |         match *self {
55 | |             TType::t1(ref x) => x as &t1,
56 | |             TType::t2(ref x) => x as &t2,
57 | |             TType::t3(ref x) => x as &t3
58 | |         }
59 | |     }
   | |_____^ ...ending here
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that method type is compatible with trait (expected fn(&TType) -> &tObject + 'static, found     fn(&TType) -> &tObject)
  --> <anon>:53:5
   |
53 |       fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a tObject {
   |  _____^ starting here...
54 | |         match *self {
55 | |             TType::t1(ref x) => x as &t1,
56 | |             TType::t2(ref x) => x as &t2,
57 | |             TType::t3(ref x) => x as &t3
58 | |         }
59 | |     }
   | |_____^ ...ending here
```

If I make the return type of `deref` `Self::Target` instead of `tObject`, it compiles fine. I do not understand this behaviour.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE]. For example, I bet you can reproduce your error with 1 or 2 enum variants instead of 3, your structs could have 0 or 1 fields, your trait could have 0 or 1 methods, you don't need anything inside of `main` etc.

Comment: Note that you will have a large number of warnings because you are not following idiomatic Rust naming conventions. Please remove all warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [MCVE](/help/mcve). Programmers use these to help narrow down the scope of a problem. For example, this MCVE rules out anything being due to the use of the `enum`, the `Rc`, any of the methods in the trait, or any of the fields in the structs. This allows us to focus on what is important:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

pub trait Trait {}

pub struct S {}
impl Trait for S {}

pub struct Container(S);

impl Deref for Container {
    type Target = Trait;

    // fn deref(&self) -> &Trait { // Fails!
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target { // Works!
        &self.0
    }
}
```

From the code, we can intuit that, somehow, `Trait` and `Self::Target` are **not** the same type. It's a bit tricky to see the type here, but this code prints out the type as a compiler error:

```
fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
    let a: Self::Target;
    &self.0
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Trait + 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
```

We don't actually care about the error, but we've discovered the type: `Trait + 'static`. Let's see what happens if we try something like that:

```
fn deref(&self) -> &(Trait + 'static) {
    &self.0
}
```

This compiles.

In case you are unfamiliar with this syntax, there are plenty of questions about it. Here are some:

- [Type definition with a trait: Differences of specifying an explicit lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27675554/155423)
- [Explicit lifetime declarations in trait objects held by structs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27790168/155423)