# How can I return an iterator over a slice?

Tags: iterator, closures, rust

```
fn main() {
    let vec: Vec<_> = (0..5).map(|n| n.to_string()).collect();

    for item in get_iterator(&vec) {
        println!("{}", item);
    }
}

fn get_iterator(s: &[String]) -> Box<Iterator<Item=String>> {
    Box::new(s.iter())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```rust
fn get_iterator<'a>(s: &'a [String]) -> Box<Iterator<Item=&'a String> + 'a> {
    Box::new(s.iter())
}
```

The trick here is that we start with a slice of items and that slice has the lifetime `'a`. [`slice::iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) returns a [`slice::Iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) with the same lifetime as the slice. The implementation of `Iterator` likewise returns references with that lifetime. We need to connect all of the lifetimes together.

That explains the `'a` in the arguments and in the `Item=&'a` part. So what's the `+ 'a` mean? There's a [complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26213294/155423) about that, and [another with more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25959806/155423). The short version is that an object with *references inside of it* may implement a trait, so we need to account for those lifetimes when talking about a trait. By default, that lifetime is `'static` as it was determined that was the usual case.

The `Box` is not strictly required, but is a normal thing you'll see when you don't want to deal with the complicated types that might underlie the implementation (or just don't want to expose the implementation). In this case, the function *could* be

```rust
fn get_iterator<'a>(s: &'a [String]) -> std::slice::Iter<'a, String> {
    s.iter()
}
```

But if you add `.skip(1)`, the type would be:

```rust
std::iter::Skip<std::slice::Iter<'a, String>>
```

And if you involve a closure, then it's currently impossible to specify the type, as closures are unique, anonymous, auto-generated types! A `Box` is required for those cases.

Comment: To me the Box makes no sense, am I missing something?